# How to address Nonsense queries to LUIS?

Tags: nlp, azure-language-understanding

I know that i can make a none intent to cover some of these, however we cannot just create every nonsense question a person could ask.

Or even if someone types in a 50 word statement.   The bigger problem is that if we get a query to LUIS, it is assigning it an intent that is not correct, without even having identified any entities either.

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

To handle these cases, it would be better to add more labeled utterances to your other intents and occasionally add the stray utterances to the None intent. When the model is better for predicting your non-None intents, the better predicting of None intents also accompany this (LUIS attempts to match to an intent rather than cutting intents out).

If intents are triggering without any entities being recognized (and thus you believe the wrong intent has been triggered), this should be handled at an application level, where you would then disambiguate the intents back to your users. If you've set the `verbose` flag to true, then you could take the top three scoring intents and present those back as options to your user. Then you can move back into the proper dialog.

After you've moved into the intent/dialog they meant to access, you can conduct a programmatic API call to [add that utterance](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c08) to the intent. Individually adding labeled utterances can be problematic (the programmatic API key has a limit of 100,000 transactions per month, and a rate of 10 transactions per second), so you can instead aggregate the utterances and [conduct batch labeling](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c09). An additional bit of info; there is a limit of 100 labeled utterance per batch upload.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the [Steven's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46453579/4937240) - in the intent window, you have the `Suggested Utternaces` tab - this is also a hint for the algorithm, kind of reinforced learning approach.